# Unable to add email template under transactional emails in magento

Tags: email, magento, email-templates

Am trying to create new invoice template on magento.When i select template and click load template the template was loading.After that i click save template the following error shoud accred.
"**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `core_email_template` (`template_code`, `template_text`, `template_styles`, `template_type`, `template_subject`, `added_at`, `modified_at`, `orig_template_code`, `orig_template_variables`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '2015-03-20 05:56:15', '2015-03-20 05:56:15', ?, ?)**". What's the problem.Help Me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have changed some core files. I suggest you to revert back to the original core files from a clean installation.

Replace all files in app > code > core from a clean installation. Make sure that you get the core files from the same Magento Version as you currently have.